# Image sitemaps -- list same images on every page?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

My website has very few images: 2 versions of the logo, a favicon, and a default user image. They are used on many pages. These images are also referenced from a */publicrelations* page.

The website also has an animated image that is only in the background of the landing page, but I don't want this indexed.

When creating the [image sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en), should I

- A: only do `<url><loc>myurl.com/publicrelations</loc>infoAboutAllTheCommonImages</url>`
- B: do what is in "A" but for every page (i.e. `<loc>urlToSomePage</loc>`), even though every page will reference the same images
- C: something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The essence of including an image sitemap is for your image to be visible on the search engine results page. Question is- do you want your favicon and logo on the search results? If NO, forget about the sitemap.

If YES, there's no need to include the same image from every page. It's not relevant to the search results to have identical images. Just choose one.